# Can't get exception message

Tags: exception, prolog

I'm using swi-prolog and trying to use exception handling. I've got a system like

```
writeAndFail(message)
    :- write(message)
    , fail.

pred(arg1, arg2)
    :- catch(
        real_pred(arg1, arg2), 
        Exception,
        writeAndFail(Exception)
    ).
```

In the body of `real_pred` I throw a string directly, e.g. `throw('message')`. The call to pred (on a suitable test case) throws the exception and catches it correctly, but the message is never written out. How can I alter this code so that the exception message is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using lowercase terms where it looks like you want variables.

The atom `message` in the predicate `writeAndFail` is, and will always be the literal atom `message`. It will not unify with anything else other than the literal atom `message`.
Calling `writeAndFail(hello)` will fail immediately because there is no predicate that matches.
The same is true for `arg1`, `arg2` in `pred`.

If you call `pred` with literal arguments, `arg1`, and `arg2` and if throw really throws a literal `'message'` then those values should unify and you should see the expected results.

Otherwise, start your variables with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Do you know the catch predicate (I think it is SWI-Specfic)? it calls the first argument, on error (the second arg so can catch an specific error) it calls the third, so I see no problem there, but in `writeAndFail` you're right.